# How to Compare two time values (from Datetime) without Date in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timer

I have put a timer on my ASPX page, Where on tick it updates the "currenttime" on a asp:label called Label1, however when the page loads I store a DateTime value called "endtime", now what i want to do is when "currenttime" equals "endtime" fire Response.Redirect(...), my code is like below,

ASPX

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000">
 </asp:Timer>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:Label CssClass="captions2" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Exam Timer"></asp:Label>
       </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>

               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />

           </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(...comparison goes here....){

        Response.Redirect("Nextpage.aspx")
        }else{
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) property:

```
if (currentTime.TimeOfDay == endTime.TimeOfDay)
```

... although I suspect you want to use `>=` instead of `==`. If you do, be careful of the situation where `endTime` is just before midnight... if `currentTime` ends up just *after* midnight, you may well still want to fire.

To be honest, it's not really clear why you only want to compare the time of day - when not just compare the full date/time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `ToString()` method. http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm use this address to rearrange date values and

```
if (currentTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")== endTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```